# mouseReleaseEvent not triggered when have drag data?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

In my test demo, the `mouseReleaseEvent` will not execute when `mouseMoveEvent` do something with `QDrag`. I want `mouseReleaseEvent` also work when i drag something.

```py
class Item2(QGraphicsItem):
    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(-50, -50, 100, 100)
    
    def paint(self, p, o, w):
        p.setBrush(Qt.red)
        p.drawRect(-50, -50, 100, 100)
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
            print('press')
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if QLineF(e.buttonDownScreenPos(Qt.LeftButton), e.screenPos()).length() > QApplication.startDragDistance():
            drag = QDrag(e.widget())
            
            data = QMimeData()
            data.setText('Test')
            
            drag.setMimeData(data)
            drag.exec()
            print('move')
    
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        print('release')

class Demo2(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.addItem(Item2())
        self.setScene(self.scene)

app = QApplication([])
demo = Demo2()
demo.resize(800, 800)
demo.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: QDrag internally "eats" the mouse release event. But, I'm afraid that you're facing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need drag&drop? Why do you need to react to a mouse release event after the drop?

Comment: @musicamante i need  to dothing something when `mouseReleaseEvent` mouse release, i think is a basic requirement.

Comment: Please, be more clear, "I need to do something" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @musicamante i need to change mouse cursor when press and when release to change another cursor style.

Comment: Please edit your code to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that tries to do exacly what you need (even if it doesn't properly work). We cannot guess what you want to do unless you clearly explain it.

Comment: @musicamante Hi friend, i had changed the code.